# Colspan adjustment in a PdfPTable / PdfPCell

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to create something like this using a `iText PdfPTable` :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|                         Content 1                          |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|              Content 2          |  Content 3  | Content 4  |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|                         Content 5                          |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|           Content 7           |       Content 7            | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

UPDATE:

I have tried creating a similar stuff but failed, which shows I definitely need to learn more.Could anybody suggest me how to construct the same and help me to learn. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: *How* is it not working?

Comment: It is working but .. I cannot get hold the idea of creating iText PdfTable, especially the row and colspan stuff. COuld you help me with that?

Comment: That's a completely different question from what you posted. Either delete the question and ask a new one or edit this one to reflect what the actual question is. Keep in mind if you ask exactly what you just did to me it will be (more than likely) closed as too broad

Comment: I am trying to create the mentioned structure. But I am unable to grasp the concept which is implemented to create the rowspans and colspans in iText Pdf table. The code I wrote was a amatuer and wrong one but that is what I tried. So, askes for help. Could you suggest me how to construct the given table structure? @tnw

Comment: Okay, again, see my first comment. What's wrong about the structure that you *do* get?

Comment: The structure I get from the code is not representing the structure I need(*mentioned first*). Or, do you want me to post the structure which the code gives me?

Comment: You are copying the code from http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable10 which produces a table as shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267169 which is an *accepted* answer. It works, but it should be obvious that you need to change some colspan and rowspan values if you want a different result. I don't see any rowspan in the desired output, so why are you mentioning rowspan in your question? Why are you using rowspan in your code?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie : thanks a lot for such contribution and effort for bringing up iText, first of all. But now I have edited my question as previously I was trying to create a similar structure. Could you help me out here?

Comment: I have written an example, but be aware that the ASCII table you created, isn't very clear. I assume that you have 3 columns and that the 1st column is double as wide as the other two. I can't be sure though. Anyway: this is a trivial question. If you need different dimensions, it's sufficient to change the widths and/or the number of columns and/or the colspans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is much simpler than the example you used for inspiration. It is good practice to add comment lines for each row, so that you can easily do the Math to calculate the colspans that are needed:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    // I see 3 columns in your example
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    // The first column appears to have double the width of the other columns
    table.setWidths(new int[]{ 2, 1, 1});
    // the first row consists of 1 cell that spans the 3 columns
    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Content 1"));
    c1.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(c1);
    // Then follows a row with normal cells
    table.addCell("Content 2");
    table.addCell("Content 3");
    table.addCell("Content 4");
    // Again we have a row with 1 cell that spans 3 columns
    PdfPCell c5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Content 5"));
    c5.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(c5);
    // Now we have a row with 1 normal cell and 1 that spans 2 columns
    table.addCell("Content 7.1");
    PdfPCell c7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Content 7.2"));
    c7.setRowspan(2);
    table.addCell(c7);
    // now we can add the table
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it. That not only solved it all but got a fair idea about spanning. Thanks

Comment: ;-) Glad the example helped.

Comment: My question was trivial, as a beginner I could not do more. But with people like you around I can easily pace-up from an amateur to a pro :-).